# Could not find package with stability dev in a version installable using your PHP version

Tags: commerce, composer

When I want to install Drupal Commerce using Composer via Git Bash terminal and using the following command:

```
$ composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore --stability dev
```

I get the following error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]   Could not find package
>   drupalcommerce/project-base with stability dev in a version
>   installable using your PHP version 5.6.40.
>
> create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source]
>   [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url
>   REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers]
>   [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs]
>   [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--]
>   [] [] []

So what can I do?

Answer (score 5):

The package that triggers the error is  drupalcommerce/project-base. If you check the [composer information for that package](https://github.com/drupalcommerce/project-base/blob/8.x/composer.json) you see:

```
  "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.8",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "composer/installers": "^1.2",
        "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6.5",
        [...]
```

As you see, it requires PHP 7.0.8 or higher. You have PHP 5.6.40. You should upgrade your PHP, not only because this package but also because PHP 7.x is much faster and PHP 5.6 is not recommended anymore, not to forget that PHP 5.6 end of life was hit a year ago, on the beginning of 2019.

Comment: Guess what, 7.0.8 is no longer supported either. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: @NoSssweat, that's right. Even 7.1 is deprecated: https://twitter.com/krakjoe/status/1201010799034195968.

Comment: For best performance and future maintenance, always use the newest PHP you can find. Drupal 9 and Commerce 3.x, scheduled for the second half of 2020 will require PHP 7.2, so anyone not using 7.2 will need to update again in 6-12 months.